# Удалить строки от определенной даты в индексе в Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных

День добрый) помогите удалить строки от определенной даты в индексе Pandas.
например вот в этой таблице как начертил удалить все строки где дата больше чем "2020-07-31 04:45:00"
и если можете напишите как поменять формат даты на    04:45 . 07-31-2020

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @timnavigate А как бы вы эту картинку переформатировали? Проблема, верхняя часть перечеркнута и OCR спотыкается.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если значения индекса отсортированы, то делается это очень просто - используйте [DataFrame.loc[...]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) "accessor" и срезы по значениям индекса:

Пример:

```
In [9]: df = pd.DataFrame(
            {"val": np.random.randint(10, size=20)},
            index=pd.date_range("2020-01-01 04:15:00", periods=20, freq="555T")
        )

In [10]: df
Out[10]:
                     val
2020-01-01 04:15:00    5
2020-01-01 13:30:00    9
2020-01-01 22:45:00    2
2020-01-02 08:00:00    7
2020-01-02 17:15:00    1
2020-01-03 02:30:00    3
2020-01-03 11:45:00    9
2020-01-03 21:00:00    7
2020-01-04 06:15:00    9
2020-01-04 15:30:00    8
2020-01-05 00:45:00    6
2020-01-05 10:00:00    9
2020-01-05 19:15:00    4
2020-01-06 04:30:00    0
2020-01-06 13:45:00    0
2020-01-06 23:00:00    7
2020-01-07 08:15:00    1
2020-01-07 17:30:00    1
2020-01-08 02:45:00    8
2020-01-08 12:00:00    4
```

решение (выбираем даты, начиная с `"2020-01-05 10:00:00"`):

```
In [11]: res = df.loc["2020-01-05 10:00:00":]
```

результат:

```
In [12]: res
Out[12]:
                     val
2020-01-05 10:00:00    9
2020-01-05 19:15:00    4
2020-01-06 04:30:00    0
2020-01-06 13:45:00    0
2020-01-06 23:00:00    7
2020-01-07 08:15:00    1
2020-01-07 17:30:00    1
2020-01-08 02:45:00    8
2020-01-08 12:00:00    4
```

---

Изменения формата даты обозначает, что мы превращаем тип данных из `datetime64` в `object` (строка). Соответственно мы теряем возможность совершать любые операции с датами (использовать `.dt` accessor, делать арифметику с `Timedelta` и многое другое, включая возможность использовать срезы, как в примере выше). Обычно формат даты/времени меняют только перед тем как экспортировать данные для отчета (например перед выгрузкой данных в Excel, HTML, etc.). Хранить же данные лучше в оригинальном формате.

В качестве примера можем добавить к фрейму дополнительный столбец с отформатированными датами:

```
In [18]: df.loc[:, "dt_str"] = df.index.strftime("%H:%M . %m-%d-%Y")

In [19]: df
Out[19]:
                     val              dt_str
2020-01-01 04:15:00    5  04:15 . 01-01-2020
2020-01-01 13:30:00    9  13:30 . 01-01-2020
2020-01-01 22:45:00    2  22:45 . 01-01-2020
2020-01-02 08:00:00    7  08:00 . 01-02-2020
2020-01-02 17:15:00    1  17:15 . 01-02-2020
2020-01-03 02:30:00    3  02:30 . 01-03-2020
2020-01-03 11:45:00    9  11:45 . 01-03-2020
2020-01-03 21:00:00    7  21:00 . 01-03-2020
2020-01-04 06:15:00    9  06:15 . 01-04-2020
2020-01-04 15:30:00    8  15:30 . 01-04-2020
2020-01-05 00:45:00    6  00:45 . 01-05-2020
2020-01-05 10:00:00    9  10:00 . 01-05-2020
2020-01-05 19:15:00    4  19:15 . 01-05-2020
2020-01-06 04:30:00    0  04:30 . 01-06-2020
2020-01-06 13:45:00    0  13:45 . 01-06-2020
2020-01-06 23:00:00    7  23:00 . 01-06-2020
2020-01-07 08:15:00    1  08:15 . 01-07-2020
2020-01-07 17:30:00    1  17:30 . 01-07-2020
2020-01-08 02:45:00    8  02:45 . 01-08-2020
2020-01-08 12:00:00    4  12:00 . 01-08-2020
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df_index = df.reset_index()
df_index = df_index[df_index.reset_index()['date'] >= datetime(year=2020, month=7, day=31)]
df_index = df_index.set_index('date')
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]